# A Sophie Germain surface & Mean Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

How is the mean curvature $ H= \dfrac{\kappa_1 +\kappa_2}{2}$ involved in a
[Surface proposed by Sophie Germain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain)

$${\dfrac {4(x^{p}-1)}{x-1}}=y^{2}\pm pz^{2} ?$$

In the following sketches it appears Gauss curvature  $K<0 \text{ for }p>0   $ and vice versa.

[image]

It is not clear if the above is an approximate solution of the isotropic biharmonic equation for plate bending / vibration mentioned in Wiki ( I cannot  access it ). She published it in later life and may contain important insights with theoretical significance in structural mechanics of Plate theory.

In simplified form static deflections appear as ( $ p$ lateral pressure, $D$ plate rigidity) square of Laplace operator :

$$\frac{\partial ^4 z}{\partial x^4}  +\frac {\partial^4 z} {\partial ^2 x\partial ^2 y} + \frac{\partial ^4 z}{\partial y^4}= \nabla ^{4}z= \dfrac{p}{D}. $$